# Seeking a M'tzudos-like commentary on Echa

Tags: product-recommendation, commentaries, lamentations-eicha, ketuvim

I'm (*b'li neder*) learning [*K'suvim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketuvim) for the first time, and am doing so with the commentary of [the *M'tzudos* (that is, *M'tzudas Tziyon* and *M'tzudas David*)](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA). I chose the *M'tzudos* because they

- are written in simple, easy to understand language;

  explain every part of every verse (or almost);

  translate any difficult words that appear in the scripture; and

  give (usually) merely an explanation of the scripture, without complex analysis and without *midrashim*.

I'm up to [*Echa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Lamentations), on which there's no commentary of the *M'tzudos*. Can anyone recommend a commentary on *Echa*, please, that meets some or all of the above criteria? (Please state which it meets and to what extent.)

Comment: I have to double-check, but I'm pretty sure the author of the chumash shai l'morah did an pseudo-Metzudot for all the megillas found in the back of the chumash, including Eicha

Comment: I have a _Qinot le-Tsh'ah be-Av_ booklet published by "SHAY LAMORA" which includes _Eikha_ with Rashi and the [pseudo-] _Metzudot_ commentary, about which it says: "הפירושים בלי כל ראשי תיבות/ והסדר עם רווח בין השורות/ למגילות **רות איכה ואסתר** / שבהם פירוש המצודות חסר/ ערכנו פירוש **בית מצודות** / מהבית ומהמקורות שמהם נשאבות/ ועל יסוד שערכו בליוורנו/ אברהם טולוסא וישראל קושטא/ ועתה נתחבר בירושלים/ ונערך מחדש בכפלים/ בעזרת השם הגדול והנורא/ במכון **שי למורא**". It seems to concur with what @Menachem says.

Comment: Many thanks to you both, Menachem, @TamirEvan. Perhaps write that up as an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

The Shay LaMora Publishing House has published Megilat Eicha with a commentary they call *Beit Metzudot*, a commentary in the style of the Metzudot for Megilot that don't have them.

You can see it on [their website here](http://shaylamora.com/product.php?prod_id=61), and you can read the text quoted by @TamirEvan ([in his comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33656/seeking-a-mtzudos-like-commentary-on-echa#comment85833_33656)) by clicking on the picture.

This is included in the Chumash Shay LaMora for Devarim as well.

Comment: I upvoted this when I first read it. I haven't given it the checkmark, though, because, sad to say, it doesn't actually help me. I'm really looking (though I didn't mention this in the question) for a text that is available either online free or in a local synagogue, and the volumes you mention are AFAICT neither.

Comment: @msh210: many synagogues have the Chumash Shai LaMora, you might check around.